# Problem in running Trio with Kivy and Socket.io

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, python-socketio, python-trio

Currently, I'm trying to run Kivy, Socket.io as coroutine of Trio. It seems that Kivy UI showing the blank screen and seem to be unresponsive. Earlier, Kivy was working with Trio, after socket.io added, it became unresponsive. Provided Sample code for the same.

```
async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
     nursery.start_soon(kivy_sample_app)
     nursery.start_soon(websocket_client.connect)
     nursery.start_soon(command_line.run)
```

Comment: What library are you using for socket.io? In general, when doing any kind of io from a trio app, you need a library that's designed for async usage *and* designed to work with trio, like trio-websocket.

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith I am using this library: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance, `python-socketio` is an asyncio library. It is not `trio`-compatible, as it uses `asyncio` functions to do the stuff.

Unfortunately, you can't just use `asyncio`-written libraries in `trio`. Both are `async` python libraries, but they use a different incompatible event loop.

Your alternatives are:

1. Use a `trio`-based socketio implementation:

   - find a `trio`-based socketio library - I'm not aware of any implementation.
   - port `python-socketio` over to `trio` or write a new implementation from scratch - you could use `anyio` here to make a library that is compatible with both `trio` and `asyncio` at the same time
2. Use a compatibility layer:

   - run `asyncio` on top of `trio` (`trio-asyncio`)
   - run `trio` on top of `asyncio` (`trio.lowlevel.start_guest_run`)

Comment: I am already using trio-asyncio but i am not receiving broadcasted event, i am able to emit event but emitted event from server not being recieved to python-socketio-asyncclient